# Solve Constrained Quadratic Programming with R

Tags: r, optimization, constraints, quadprog, quadratic-programming

I really love R but from time to time it really gives me a headache...

I have the following simple quadratic minimization problem which can be formulated and solved within no time in Excel (click on picture to enlarge):

[image]

and

[image: ![enter image description here]

The problem itself is pretty straightforward: I want to minimize `(w1^2+w2^2)/2` by finding the best combination of `w1`,`w2` and `b` under the constraints that for all `Y*(w1*X1+w2*X2+b) >= 1`

I know that there is the `quadprog` package for solving these kinds of problems but I find it so unintuitive that I am not able to specify the problem correctly :-(  I hate to say it but Excel seems to be better suited for specifying optimization problems like these :-(((

**My question**
How to formulate the above problem correctly so that it can be solved with R (no matter which package) and the program arrives at the correct values for `w1`, `w2` and `b` (as can be seen in the picture above). Please don't just post links but please give actual code that works. It would be great if you could comment your code so it becomes clear why you do the things you do. Thank you!

The necessary data is here:

```
data <- matrix(c(2.947814,6.626878, 1,
                 2.530388,7.785050, 1,
                 3.566991,5.651046, 1,
                 3.156983,5.467077, 1,
                 2.582346,4.457777,-1,
                 2.155826,6.222343,-1,
                 3.273418,3.520687,-1),ncol=3,byrow=T)
colnames(data) <- c("X1","X2","y")
```

**Addendum**
Some people took offense at my request to provide code (and not simply links). I apologized for that and gave my reasons that I did not find any good approaches in the answers so far on SO. The deeper reason for that is that the problem is unusual in the sense that `b` is only in the constraint and not in the objective function. So I still think that this question is a good fit for SO.

Comment: That Excel picture doesn't tell me what you actually want to achieve. You should explain that in the question. Excel seems irrelevant for your actual question.

Comment: If you think I'm going to figure out these Excel cell references, think again.

Comment: @Roland: The problem itself is pretty straightforward, I edited the question accordingly - is this better now?

Comment: Here are many questions and answers on the topic. I find it rude that you demand an answer and no links. This is not a code-writing service, nor are we your employees. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+quadratic+optimization. You are not the first person to inqure about optimzation. The point of SO is to create repository of questions and answers that can be researched later. So we "just post links" sometimes to use the information that has already been shared.

Comment: @PierreLafortune: If you find this rude then I have to apologize. I saw many of the questions and answers and guess what: I am still not able to solve the above problem with R - this is why I asked the question (and not to offend you).

Comment: @PierreLafortune: See my addendum and cryo111's answer and please reconsider your harsh criticism (I did not want to imply that you are my employee!) and your downvote - Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, the problem is a little tricky because `b` is only present in the inequality constraint matrix but not in the objective function. Therefore the matrix in the quadratic programming problem is only positive semidefinite but not positive definite.

My approach is therefore to set the matrix entry corresponding to `b` to a very small value - in my case `1e-9`. Someone else more familiar with such optimization problems might know how to solve the problem properly...

Calculate `solve.QP` input

```
c1=data[,"X1"]*data[,"y"]
c2=data[,"X2"]*data[,"y"]

#I use 1e-9 for the b entry
Dmat=matrix(`[<-`(numeric(9),c(1,5,9),c(1,1,1e-9)),3,3)
dvec=rep(0,3)
Amat=cbind(c1,c2,data[,"y"])
bvec=rep(1,nrow(Amat))
```

Solve with `solve.QP`

```
library(quadprog)
sol=solve.QP(Dmat=Dmat,dvec=dvec,Amat=t(Amat),bvec=bvec)$solution
sol
#[1]   2.903910   1.201258 -14.734964
```

Same as excel.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference: this problem can also be solved quite intuitively using the `CVXR` package, which provides an interface for convex optimization problems in R:

```
# Install and load the CVXR package
if (!requireNamespace("CVXR", quietly = TRUE)) {
  install.packages("CVXR")
}
library(CVXR)
# Define the data
data <- matrix(c(2.947814,6.626878, 1,
                 2.530388,7.785050, 1,
                 3.566991,5.651046, 1,
                 3.156983,5.467077, 1,
                 2.582346,4.457777,-1,
                 2.155826,6.222343,-1,
                 3.273418,3.520687,-1), ncol = 3, byrow = T)
colnames(data) <- c("X1", "X2", "y")

# Define the variables and parameters
w <- Variable(2)
b <- Variable()

# Define the constraints
constraints <- list()
for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
  constraints[[i]] <- data[i, "y"] * (sum(data[i, 1:2] * w) + b) >= 1
}

# Define the objective function
objective <- Minimize(sum(w^2)/2)

# Solve the problem
problem <- Problem(objective, constraints)
result <- solve(problem)

# Print the results
cat("w1:", result$getValue(w)[1], "\nw2:", result$getValue(w)[2], "\nb:", result$getValue(b))
## w1: 2.90391 
## w2: 1.201258 
## b: -14.73496
```